# Disallow/Redirect C++ delete?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I have a module (dll/so) which exports a single factory function which returns an object then called. Using the interface (pure-virtual) users of the module can then create different objects. All object creation is through the interface, and therefore takes place using the run-time associated with my module and not the application run-time.

As the allocation is taking place inside the module, the deletion also needs to be, because if the application has a different run-time to my module, gpf/segfault time. so I have a "release" member, which performs a self-delete.

```
void foo::release(void) 
{
    delete this;
}
```

Everything is working fine, but it does require that the user of the module behaves.

My question is:

- Is it possible to stop someone issuing a delete on my object directly (Or redirect it to delete from my modules memory pool)?
- If not as a backup plan, is it possible to detect this in my object, so I can throw an assertion to force good behavior?

E.G:

```
iFoo* foo = createFoo ();
foo->release();           // Allowed and expected
delete foo;               // Disallowed
```

Comment: Have you considered the "making private destructor" option?

Comment: A user who choses not to behave can break you in many, many ways. Make your interfaces easy to use right and hard to use wrong, and don't worry too much about malicious intent.

Comment: Perhaps returning a smart pointer is in order? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: @dave, can this be used for interfaces? My interfaces are 100% pure. The client app only knows about the interface, would a private "destructor" in the implementation headers hidden inside the module still be caught? if so, that would completely solve my concern.

Comment: @Chris, declaring a private destructor prevents the class from being inherited, so it should be *protected*. However, if you can't prevent child classes which extend your pure interfaces to implement  *public* destructors, probably this solution does not fit your problem.

Comment: @dave, i'll have to play with this. I'm not concerned about deliberate miss use as this is an internal tool, only accidental miss use. Besides anyone who really wants to hack an object can just hack around the vptr level and get everything they need, protected, private, it don't matter. Cheers for the path of investigation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you're right, I've read somewhere probably on Artima, about the same thing. Don't defend too much, it is not worth it. just can't find the damn article again

Comment: The more I think about it, I actually think the suggestion @dave made about declaring a protected destructor in your interface may actually do precisely what you're wanting to do. I'll write up an answer with some code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments to the OP, @dave made a suggestion to declare the destructors in your pure interfaces to be `protected` instead of `public`. This would outright prevent external code (that is, external to implementation classes) from invoking `delete`.

For example:

```
class IFoo
{
protected:
    virtual ~IFoo() { }

public:
    virtual void release() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo
{
public:
    void release() override
    {
        delete this;
    }
};

IFoo* createFoo()
{
    return new Foo();
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = createFoo();
    foo->release();  // Expected
    delete foo;      // Cannot access protected destructor of IFoo

    Return 0;
}
```

Since your factory functions only expose the pure interfaces, this approach doesn't break down if an implementation class happens to provide a public destructor. If `Foo` declared a public destructor, a compiler error would still occur in `main` because `main` doesn't know that it's actually dealing with a `Foo`.

Comment: Hi Lilshieste, thx for the demo. I believe this is the solution I need. One question i'm curious about. Does the virtual destructor need to be in the interface file for the compiler to pick up the error? I'm guessing it will because how would it know. Also I did not realize SO allowed posting of more than one answer from the same person. Neat, thx.

Comment: @Chris At first, I didn't know I could post another answer either (had to check the Meta site). And you are correct - the virtual destructor needs to be in the interface file in order for everything to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

**On Edit:** This approach only makes it more difficult for users to delete the resource - it doesn't outright prevent it. (I'll refrain from deleting this answer, since it might still be useful.)

If you really want keep someone from invoking delete on your objects, make it illegal for them to do so - return a value type from your factory function.

The value type could be a thin wrapper around the actual object and could provide pointer semantics, a la smart pointers.

A rough example:

```
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual ~IFoo() { }

    virtual void release() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo
{
public:
    Foo() { }

    void release() override
    {
        delete this;
    }
};

// Value type with pointer semantics
template <class T>
class Undeletable
{
private:
    T* m_resource;

public:
    Undeletable(T* resource)
        : m_resource(resource)
    {
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return m_resource;
    }
};

// Old factory function
IFoo* createFoo()
{
    return new Foo();
}

// New factory function
Undeletable<IFoo> createSafeFoo()
{
    return Undeletable<IFoo>(createFoo());
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = createFoo();
    foo->release();  // Expected
    delete foo;      // Possible but DO NOT WANT

    auto safeFoo = createSafeFoo();
    safeFoo->release(); // Expected
    delete safeFoo;     // Compiler says NOPE

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this only obfuscates the fact that the user can still delete the resource. For example:

```
delete safeFoo.operator->(); // Deletes the resource
```